# Redirect stylesheets through secure url to a different server

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, https, mod-proxy

I have a domain `http://services.mydomain.com` which has a secure login through a secure central provider (`https://secure.mydomain.com`) on a different server with proxypass. When I go to the login page I am redirected to `https://secure.mydomain.com/services`. The application page is rendered fine but I get a 404 for all of the `.css` and `.js` files, as it is looking for `https://secure.mydomain.com/services/style.css`. The stylesheet is located at `http://services.mydomain.com/style.css`

I have managed to redirect the urls via apache rewrites but they now render as unsecure items on a secure page.

Here is the rewrite rule I have used:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js|swf)$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://services.mydomain.com/style.css
```

Is there a way to redirect to these files through a secure url?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get your `https` service to serve the resources directly (without a redirect) if you want to get rid of the insecure resources warnings.

You should be able to accomplish this with a `ProxyPass` exception (a `!` for the destination) and potentially an `Alias` to map to the files from the secure host; if you can provide your vhost configurations then I can be more specific about what is needed.